# Laravel MongoDB change write concern from connection string

Tags: laravel, mongodb

how can I change the `write concern` of my MongoDB connection with Laravel, any further informations about the write concern in mongoDB would be appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can set your write concern on the connection level by setting the `w` parameter inside the connection string : 
`mongodb+srv://Host_Credentials/database?retryWrites=true&w=1`
you can set it by changing the `w` parameter.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/